# Unable to mount a 1TB external drive on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, usb, external-hard-drive, mount

When I plug my external hard drive in the USB port, it doesn't get auto mounted. So I did a `sudo fdisk -l` but was unable to find an entry for my external drive.

Then I did a `dmesg` and found the following:

```
[19681.800038] usb 1-7: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[19682.709696] usb 1-7: New USB device found, idVendor=0480, idProduct=a007
[19682.709703] usb 1-7: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=1
[19682.709708] usb 1-7: Product: External USB 3.0
[19682.709711] usb 1-7: Manufacturer: TOSHIBA
[19682.709715] usb 1-7: SerialNumber: 20130212005464F
[19682.709997] usb-storage 1-7:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[19682.710878] scsi10 : usb-storage 1-7:1.0
[19683.708858] scsi 10:0:0:0: Direct-Access     TOSHIBA  External USB 3.0 0    PQ: 0 ANSI: 6
[19683.709303] sd 10:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[19683.717646] sd 10:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Which means the system detected it, but I cannot find an entry in `fdisk -l`.  What are my options here ? How Do I get my drive to mount?

Just for reference, here is the `demsg` output for when an USB drive *did* automount:

```
[19581.904033] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 10 using ehci-pci
    [19584.104033] usb 1-8: new high-speed USB device number 12 using ehci-pci
    [19584.238028] usb 1-8: New USB device found, idVendor=03f0, idProduct=ae07
    [19584.238034] usb 1-8: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
    [19584.238038] usb 1-8: Product: v250w
    [19584.238042] usb 1-8: Manufacturer: HP
    [19584.238045] usb 1-8: SerialNumber: ACAF21D0500019457
    [19584.238336] usb-storage 1-8:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
    [19584.239243] scsi9 : usb-storage 1-8:1.0
    [19585.651328] scsi 9:0:0:0: Direct-Access     hp       v250w            1100 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
    [19585.652546] sd 9:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 0
    [19585.653694] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] 63901440 512-byte logical blocks: (32.7 GB/30.4 GiB)
    [19585.654577] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Write Protect is off
    [19585.654583] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Mode Sense: 43 00 00 00
    [19585.657059] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
    [19585.657065] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
    [19585.662040] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
    [19585.662047] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
    [19585.662940]  sdc: sdc1
    [19585.667676] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] No Caching mode page found
    [19585.667683] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through
    [19585.667688] sd 9:0:0:0: [sdc] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

Comment: Can you add what (known) partitions are on the disk and what filesystem the disk is, please!

Comment: @Hi Chris, know nothing about the partitions. It belongs to a friend. The filesystem is NTFS for sure as my friend is an exclusive Windows user.

Comment: Do you have access to a Windows machine? The disk MAY have been removed unsafely and needs a `chkdsk` running on it...

Comment: I do. Thanks for the tip. I know for sure that the device was removed unsafely - friend said he was formatting the drive for me when he lost power !

Comment: That shouldn't have affected the partition table, though. The lack of a line like the `sdc: sdc1` partition table scan result indicates that the partition table is broken, non-existent or in an unknown format. Is the drive a "dynamic" disk or whatever Windows calls it? (Don't know off hand if that applies, but it might.)

Comment: If the disk was being formatted by the "friend" before giving it to you, could you just plug it into Windows and re-initialise/format it?

Comment: The disk does not get detected in windows as well. Not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @Wildling I know its been couple of year, but did you able to resolve the mentioned issue?

Comment: Yeah, but I don't remember how I fixed it. I still use that same external drive. Autoplay works now.